# JavaScript and content change after load - countdown timer from date

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to have a simple countdown timer that converts a time given on a page to a countdown.

It works, **but** my current issue is how the normal date is shown and then **later** it's parsed by the JavaScript. I want it parsed by JS right away so a user doesn't see it flicking between the date and the countdown timer.

It converts this to the countdown:

```
<span class="countdown">12/10/20 13:10:00</span>
```

This is the code:

```
if ($('.countdown').length)
{
    $.each( $('.countdown'), function( key, value ) 
    {
        var time_listed = $(value).text();
        var countdown_object = $(value);
                    
        // Set the date we're counting down to
        var countDownDate = new Date(time_listed).getTime();

        // Update the count down every 1 second
        var x = setInterval(function() 
        {
            // Get today's date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now and the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
            countdown_object.text (days + " days " + hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");

            // If the count down is finished, write some text
            if (distance < 0) 
            {
                clearInterval(x);
                countdown_object.text("EXPIRED");
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

What I am asking for, is suggestions on how to get around this problem. Is the only way to have it loaded before the HTML or what? I'm confused on the best practices for this. Everywhere keeps telling me to defer JavaScript loading...but what about stuff like this that changes the content?

In cases like this, is it a good idea to have a "core" file for content-changing stuff that loads right away, then the rest after the content or what?

Comment: Not at all clear what specific problem is here

Comment: you code works... so what is exactly the problem?

Comment: Explained a little more in an edit.

Comment: Do not show the countdown (like, use `display: none` to hide it), and only show it when the code has initialized and ready to start counting down proper.

Comment: That doesn't really solve the issue though, then it's nothing and then suddenly something will appear.

Comment: Could use a data attribute instead of text

Comment: How does that actually change anything and fix the issue?

Comment: Your code will take time to initialize: so there will **always** be a flash of content in a way or another. It's up to you to decide how to elegantly handle it in: fade it in, or one way or another. You can't run the script before the page is loaded: so there will always be an arbitrary delay that is unavoidable.

Comment: Well if you are asking how this can be made instantaneous there are a lot of factors involved including all the other code being loaded. We have no visibility into all those factors and I suspect you need to lower your expectations or adjust thinking. A loading icon could be used also until your code initializes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems comes from setInterval not executing automatically , which is normal. Here's a work around it:

```js
if ($('.countdown').length)
{
    $.each( $('.countdown'), function( key, value ) 
    {
        var time_listed = $(value).text();
        var countdown_object = $(value);
                    
        // Set the date we're counting down to
        var countDownDate = new Date(time_listed).getTime();
var counterFunction = function() 
        {
            // Get today's date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now and the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
            countdown_object.text (days + " days " + hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");

            // If the count down is finished, write some text
            if (distance < 0) 
            {
                clearInterval(x);
                countdown_object.text("EXPIRED");
            }
            return counterFunction;
        }
        // Update the count down every 1 second
        var x = setInterval(counterFunction(), 1000);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="countdown">12/10/20 13:10:00</span>
```

Comment: Boom! That was it exactly, now it's basically instant minus perhaps a few milliseconds when grabbing the JS fresh. Once it's in the cache it looks instant. Exactly what the issue was, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to put the date in data-date attr, like this:

```
  <span data-date="12/10/20 13:10:00" class="countdown"></span>
```

than the script:

```
if ($('.countdown').length)
{
    $.each( $('.countdown'), function( key, value ) 
    {
        var time_listed = $(value).attr("data-date");
        var countdown_object = $(value);
                    
        // Set the date we're counting down to
        var countDownDate = new Date(time_listed).getTime();

        // Update the count down every 1 second
        var x = setInterval(function() 
        {
            // Get today's date and time
            var now = new Date().getTime();

            // Find the distance between now and the count down date
            var distance = countDownDate - now;

            // Time calculations for days, hours, minutes and seconds
            var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
            var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
            var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
            var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

            // Display the result in the element with id="demo"
            countdown_object.text (days + " days " + hours + "h "
            + minutes + "m " + seconds + "s ");

            // If the count down is finished, write some text
            if (distance < 0) 
            {
                clearInterval(x);
                countdown_object.text("EXPIRED");
            }
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/750o1neh/